# how to hide column for XTemplate in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

```js
'<table border="0">',
                '<tr>',
                '<th><b>'+WtfGlobal.getLocaleText("el.shift.daystatus")+'</b></th>',
                '</tr>',
                '<tpl for="workingname">',
                '<tr align="left">',
                '<td>',
                '{.}',
                '</td>',
                '</tr>',
                '</tpl>',
                '</table>',
```

this column show only true condition...
can you please tell me anyone how to hide this column if condition is false.

Answer (score 0):

Ext.XTemplate supports pretty advanced internal logic including branching. You have  construct, , . That should be enough to implement what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```js
'<table border="0">',
                '<tpl if="isEnableOTDayWise == true">',
                '<tr>',
                '<th><b>'+WtfGlobal.getLocaleText("el.shift.OTTypes")+'</b></th>',
                '</tr>',
                '<tpl for="OTflag">',
                '<tr align="left">',
                '<td>',
                '{.}',
                '</td>',
                '</tr>',
                '</tpl>',
                '</tpl>',
                '</table>',
                '</td>',
                '</tr>',
                '</table>'
```

if isEnableOTDayWise==true than show this column other wise doe's not show this column..